# Dividing integers in C rounds the value down / gives zero as a result

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to do some arithmetic on integers. The problem is when I'm trying to do division to get a double as a result, the result is always 0.00000000000000000000, even though this is obviously not true for something like ((7 * 207) / 6790). I have tried type-casting the formulas, but I still get the same result.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
int o12 = 7, o21 = 207, numTokens = 6790;
double e11 = ((o12 * o21) / numTokens);
printf(".%20lf", e11); // prints 0.00000000000000000000
```

Comment: Could you provide an real-world example how to run this code? What's the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the actual values, the following holds:

```
int / int = int
```

The output will not be cast to a non-`int` type automatically.

So the output will be floored to an `int` when doing division.

What you want to do is force any of these to happen:

```
double / int = double
float / int = float
int / double = double
int / float = float
```

<sub>The above involves an automatic [widening conversion](https://codingfox.com/3-10-widening-and-narrowing-of-primitive-conversions/) - note that only one needs to be a floating point value.</sub>

You can do this by either:

- Putting a `(double)` or `(float)` before one of your values to cast it to the corresponding type or
- Changing one or more of the variables to `double` or `float`

Note that a cast like `(double)(int / int)` will not work, as this first does the integer division (which returns an `int`, and thus floors the value) and only then casts the result to `double` (this will be the same as simply trying to assign it to a `double` without any casting, as you've done).

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly true for an expression such as `((7 * 207) / 6790)` that the result is `0`, or `0.0` if you think in `double`.

The expression only has integers, so it will be computed as an integer multiplication followed by an integer division.

You need to cast to a floating-point type to change that, e.g. `((7 * 207) / 6790.0)`.

Many poeple seem to expect the right-hand side of an assignment to be automatically "adjusted" by the type of the target variable: this is not how it works. The *result* is converted, but that doesn't affect any "inner" operations in the right-hand  expression. In your code:

```
e11 = ((o12 * o21) / numTokens);
```

All of `o12`, `o21` and `numTokens` are integer, so that expression is evaluated as integer, then converted to floating-point since `e11` is `double`.

This like doing

```
const double a_quarter = 1 / 4;
```

this is just a simpler case of the same problem: the expression is evaluated *first*, then the result (the integer `0`) is converted to double and stored. That's how the language works.

The fix is to cast:

```
e11 = ((o12 * o21) / (double) numTokens);
```

Comment: I see. Thank you!  I was casting in the wrong place previously.

Answer (score 0):

You must cast these numbers to `double` before division. When you perform division on `int` the result is also an integer rounded towards zero, e.g. `1 / 2 == 0`, but `1.0 / 2.0 == 0.5`.

Answer (score 0):

If the operands are integer, C will perform integer arithmetic. That is, `1/4 == 0`. However, if you force an operand to be `double`, then the arithmetic will take fractional parts into account. So:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 4;
double c = 1.0

double d = a/b;         // d == 0.0
double e = c/b;         // e == 0.25
double f = (double)a/b; // f == 0.25
```